# Comunicación con webService

Tags: java, android, webservice

Estoy haciendo la comicación con un webService. Los primeros métodos que tengo que consultar me funionan perfectamente, en uno tengo que recuperar un apartado del header, en otro del cuerpo en forma de text, pero el problema viene cuando tengo que recuperar un Json en el cuerpo. Por alguna razón que desconozco aparece en html, y no viene la información. Siguiendo los pasos con el postman me aparece bien.  ¿alguna idea?

```
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(
                        EndUrl).openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
                conn.setRequestMethod(typeMethod);
```

El contentType es para este método application/json

```
conn.getResponseCode()
```

me da 200 ok,

```
final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                String Response = "";
                String currentLine;

                while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(currentLine);
                    Response += currentLine;
                }
```

Tanto response como Response es lo mismo (solo era por probar alternativas) y es aquí donde en vez de ser Json es html...

Gracias.

Comment: Hola, en postman te viene un json pero con este metodo te viene un html? podrias agregar el json que muestra postman y mas importante el html que estas recibiendo?

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. He visto que aunque yo le ponga "Content-Type", "application/json" en la cabecera de la respuesta (conn.getHeaderFields()/content-type) me pone text/html;charset=ISO-8859-15 por eso me da un resultado no deseado. ¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo? gracias